# Javafx: Ubuntu undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_once

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, javafx

I tried to generate deb file using mvn jfx:native. I ran the deb on ubuntu and it failed due to undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_once.

Please notice that this issue happens on ubuntu only.

Comment: I've faced a similar problem a while ago and its probably a linking problem can you post the whole error!

Comment: This is the error :
symbol lookup error: /tmp/jna-3506402/jna9194104288338741859.tmp: undefined symbol: pthread_once

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue on a Linux Debian 8.5. I am guessing that your are using JNA in your app (like me). I'm very interested in any way to resolve this issue.